# Elasticsearch Error when RabbitMQ queue is too large

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I'm publishing thousands of URL to my Queue in RabbitMQ, for analysis. Once consumed, results are stored in ElasticSearch.

For some reasons, when the Queue becomes too long, I get an ElasticSearch Error.

I'm getting the same issue if I increase the `ConsumeChannel.prefetch` above 1.

I'm running the different services via docker-compose.

```
Elasticsearch ERROR: 2021-02-07T13:05:30Z
  Error: Request error, retrying
  POST http://localhost:9200/test_20210207/_doc => connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
      at Log.error
```

Comment: the rabbitmq queue become large because you have connection problem with elasticsearch. check elasticsearch logs.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch was erroring because Docker resources memory was, by default, to small.
Increasing it solved the issue.